# using localtime function to get users local time in php

Tags: php, localtime

I am trying to find a way to get the local time of the user using php, and not rely on the timezone set in `php.ini`. I found the function `localtime()`, but this does not work, it still gives me the time based on the timezone set in `php.ini`. I'm staring to believe that the local time is not accessible using server side script as it can with client side script, below is what I tried, but not working. Thanks for reading

```
$time = localtime(time(),true);

$h = $time['tm_hour'];
$m = $time['tm_min'];
$s = $time['tm_sec'];

$localTime = $h.":".$m.":".$s;
```

Comment: You're right, the client's timezone/local time is not available on the server side unless the client has specifically told the server what it is

Comment: I thought so, though it seems weired php would have a function called localtime. A little misleading

Comment: It is the local time of the server running PHP code, and the function is using the same name as the C std library ...

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot get the location of the user and have a database that maps this information to a timezone you are usually out of luck.

However, if you are in html context you may get the requested information using javascript (and send it back to the server):

```
var x = new Date();
var currentTimeZoneOffsetInHours = x.getTimezoneOffset() / 60;
```

[Read more @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset)

Using this information you can build the users local time on the server side using basic date functions.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I don't think I'll go to such measures, it's not essential to the website it would just make  more sense. +1